# How to add multiple properties to objects more efficiently

Tags: java, object, properties

I've been messing around with Java, and I've set a JButton as so:

`JButton operator = new JButton;`

When I try to set a property for JButton operator, it works:

`operator.setFont(new Font("Chalkboard", Font.PLAIN, 30));`

However, when I try to set multiple properties (which is what I want to do), it throws an error - when I do it this way!

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(200, 200);
operator.setFont(new Font("Chalkboard", Font.PLAIN, 30))
.setPreferredSize(d)
.setBackground(Color.RED);
// Error: "Cannot invoke preferredSize(Dimension) on the primitive type void"
```

How exactly would I set multiple properties for the object `operator`? I don't want to have to do this-

```
operator.setFont(new Font("Chalkboard"), Font.PLAIN, 30));
operator.setPreferredSize(d);
operator.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

because if I wanted to set TWENTY properties to the object for example (in this case, a JButton), it would be very tedious to keep writing it over and over!

```
operator.setProperty1("test");
operator.setProperty2("test");
operator.setProperty3("test");
operator.setProperty4("test");
operator.setProperty5("test"); // too much work lol
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `set` method doesn't return the object itself, you can't chain the setters. The error you're getting, "cannot invoke...on void" will happen for any set method whose signature is like `void setSomething(Object something)`.

The kind of thing you're referring to is used more in builder patterns.

```
public class SomeObject {

    private String name;

    private String colour;

    public SomeObject name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public SomeObject colour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
        return this;
    }
}
```

In this example you can use `SomeObject` like

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject().name("A name").colour("red");
```

In the example you provided, if the various `setProperty` methods are `void` methods, you have to do it the way it appears in your question; so in your case, yes, 20 different `operator.setProperty`... are necessary.

This is perhaps a lot of work but it's less painful than a constructor with 20 arguments.

Comment: So then - is there a more efficient way of setting multiple properties to objects?

Comment: In your specific case, no. I updated the answer with more detail. A good book to read would be Clean Code by Robert C. Martin.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the recommendation.